# SAPUI5 Input not showing validation error in Wizard Step

Tags: sapui5

I have the following Input component setup in a SAPUI5 app as part of Table ColumnList Item cell in a Wizard Step.

```
<Input value="{parts: ['service>netPrice', 'service>currency'], type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Currency', formatOptions: {showMeasure: false} }" />
```

If I enter a . (decimal point) which, for example is an invalid character for the JEN currency (JPY), why is the input not redded out with an 'invalid entry' error message?

I appreciate the issue may not be related to currency, but rather the Input being part of a Wizard Step perhaps? Either way, I would have expected some sort of automatic UI5 validation on the Input

Any Idea why nothing would show?

Answer (score 0):

Solution was

```
 "sap.ui5": {
        "handleValidation": true, 
...
```

In the manifest.json